# How to read test data from external JSON file and compare with postman response?

Tags: api, postman

I have array of test data json file in local machine. I am writing a test in postman and trying to compare the response against the test data. Instead of doing it in collection runner, is it possible to pass the test data into Tests and compare with the response?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that is currently supported in Postman:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7210

Alternatively what you could do

1. Copy/paste content of file (assuming it's not huge) and read into a variable which you could then do a string comparison against.
2. Store the content of the file in an endpoint where you can request it in the pre-request script, save it to a variable then do string comparison.

Neither solution is pretty in my opinion but probably the best you can do.